# when calling the service method from the client i am getting this error message

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

WCF SERVERICE when calling the service method from the client i am getting this error message. I have changed the client config as well as the service config.. and enabled the trace for the service.. still not able to figure out..

```
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>TestTPIXmlService.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/TPIEngine. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionRequestChannelGeneric`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
at TestTPIXmlService.myService.XmlServiceInterface.TPI_Xml_Send(String clientId, String clientPwd, String[] xmlList)
at TestTPIXmlService.myService.XmlServiceInterfaceClient.TPI_Xml_Send(String clientId, String clientPwd, String[] xmlList)
at TestTPIXmlService.Program.sendFiletoWcf()
at TestTPIXmlService.Program.Main(String[] args)
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/TPIEngine. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---&gt; System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---&gt; System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
<System.Diagnostics xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/08/System.Diagnostics">
<LogicalOperationStack></LogicalOperationStack>
<Timestamp>28383466303172</Timestamp>
</System.Diagnostics>
</ApplicationData>
```

Comment: Can you show us your client and server bindings?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you are having problems, but without seeing the server logs (like the exception tells you), we can't help.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have the firewall blocking the port on which your service is. Also make sure that some antivirus is not blocking the call to the service

Answer (score 0):

`Connection Close` is usually a security issue. So you could not authenticate with the server hence connection is closed.

- First you need to look at the server to find out what is happening. The error will be more readable at the server.
- Second, share your binding so we can help more
- You need to enable (for debugging) errors to be passed to the client. That needs to be set on the server.

Comment: The service is deployed on my local desktop and i am writing the client application for testing the service..

Comment: Here is the Client EndPOint  <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/TPIEngine" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_XmlServiceInterface" contract="myService.XmlServiceInterface"
                name="WSHttpBinding_XmlServiceInterface" behaviorConfiguration="MaxBehavior">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="bahadur.shaik@xxx.local" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>

Comment: <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="MaxBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

Comment: Add it to the question not comment

Comment: And the bindings   <binding name="WSHttpBinding_XmlServiceInterface" closeTimeout="10:05:00"
                    openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">

Comment: Thanks aliostad, this site does allow my to paste the config file.. since it is big.. do you have any email address. i can send it

Comment: Share it here please. Only the relevant bits.